# how to have the same gradient fill background on all slides

Tags: keynote

How do you change the background gradient fill for all slides. I created a nice gradient fill for the first slide and I need it to come across all of the slides for the presentation. thank you

Comment: how did you create the gradient fill in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

1) You have to edit a "Master Slide" (menu: View -> Show Master Slides).

2) Then Edit the master slide (you can duplicate it if you don't want to touch the original).

3) This automatically applies to all the slides.

See how the Slide 1 has now a gradient, even tho I have modified a Master Slide.

[image: Keynote]

Play around (and Google) Master Slides in Keynote and you will likely understand how it works.